# same item added multiple times in a array while using push or concat in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to push items into an array using for loop and wanted to use the filled in array. The 'push' or 'concat' happens successfully. But the problem is when there are two items looped in, the second time when the loop run pushes the second time twice in inside the array, instead of concatenating with the first item that is loop.

```
var response_items = {};
var basketItems = [];

for (var i = 0; i < basketRequest.items.length; i++) {

            basket_item_code = basketRequest.items[i].item_code;
            response_items.item_code = basket_item_code;
            basket_item_price = basketRequest.items[i].price;
            response_items.price = basket_item_price;
            basket_item_qty = basketRequest.items[i].qty;
            response_items.qty = basket_item_qty;
            item_sub_total = basket_item_price * basket_item_qty;
            sub_total = sub_total + item_sub_total;
            response_items.fee = '800';
            basketItems.push(response_items);
            //basketItems= basketItems.concat(response_items);
            console.log (i,'basketItems concatetw ...',  basketItems);
        }
```

Current Input

```
"items":[{
            "item_code": "234234",
            "price": "908",
            "qty": "5"
        },
        {
            "item_code": "787878777",
            "price": "1008",
            "qty": "5"
        }]
```

Current O/p:

```
"items": [
        {
            "item_code": "787878777",
            "price": "1008",
            "qty": "5",
            "fee": "800"
        },
        {
            "item_code": "787878777",
            "price": "1008",
            "qty": "5",
            "fee": "800"
        }
    ]
```

Desired O/p:

```
"items":[{
            "item_code": "234234",
            "price": "908",
            "qty": "5"
        },
        {
            "item_code": "787878777",
            "price": "1008",
            "qty": "5"
        }]
```

Comment: Put var response_items = {}; into the loop

Comment: Thank you Jonas W for pointing out the blunder! Placing var response_items = {}; into the loop resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Youre putting the same object into the array multiple times. However your code isnt really readable. Thats how i would do it:

```
var basket_items = basketRequest.items.map(basket=>({
        item_code:basket.item_code,
        price:basket.price,
        qty:basket.qty,
        sub_total:(+basket.sub_total ||0) + basket.price * basket.qty,
        fee:'800'
}));
```

Note that you need to convert sub_total to a number (+), and it doesnt appear in your input.

http://jsbin.com/pudapujaca/edit?console

Answer (score 0):

Right now, you are putting the same object reference in the array and then changing the data in the object. So it changes in both places. You need to put the `response_items` object declaration inside the loop so that a new object is created and added to the array for each iteration.